# ASP Web Forms fire code behind event on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, code-behind

I have ASP.NET WEB FORMS apps

```
<asp:Button ID="DeleteDealsButton" runat="server" Text="Delete" />
```

```
function btnDeleteClick() {
    var result = confirm("Want to delete all Deals?");
    if (result) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$("#MainContent_DeleteDealsButton").on("click", function() {
        if (btnDeleteClick()) {})
```

On this button I have sample javascript alert to ask OK or Cancel.I want if choise OK to fire CODE BEHIND method call DeleteDealsButton_Click, if it Cancel to do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change button defination to,

```
<asp:Button ID="DeleteDealsButton" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Want to delete all Deals?')" />
```

No need for any javascript function.

Comment: But after user choice OK i want code continue to code behind event call DeleteDealsButton_Click !

Comment: Yes. It will execute button's click event, if user clicks on OK button. It will cancel event, if user clicks on cancel button.

Comment: If this works, can you please mark this answer as a accepted solution. And please vote up this answer.

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
function btnDeleteClick() {
var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
 confirm_value.type = "hidden";
 confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
 confirm_value.value = "No";
var result = confirm("Want to delete all Deals?");
if (result) {
    confirm_value.value = "Yes";
    __doPostBack('DeleteDealsButton', '')
    return true;
} else {
    confirm_value.value = "No";
    return false;
}
}
```

In your .Aspx file Change your button code to like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="DeleteDealsButton" OnClientClick=" return btnDeleteClick()" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="DeleteDealsButton_Click" />
```

In your .Aspx.cs file

```
protected void DeleteDealsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
     if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(confirmValue) && confirmValue.Equals("Yes"))
     {
     }
}
```

Comment: Not working I have NullReferenceException on confirmValue.Equals("Yes")